# How to ping an IP address from a VueJS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ping

Working on VueJS application, I want to create a function that pings a specific IP address and returns the time and status.

1- I used [ping-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping-lite) but I got this error: `Could not detect your ping binary.`.
I saw that in the node module they are checking the machine OS (running on Windows and WSL) and throwing that error if failing.

2- I then tried [ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) and I got this error:

```
(Promise/async): "TypeError: net.isIPv6 is not a function"
```

I was trying to executing the example code from their npm/github page:

```js
var ping = require('ping');
    
var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
    
for(let host of hosts){
       let res = await ping.promise.probe(host);
       console.log(res);
   }
```

I wonder if the problems are related and if it's something with my environment/machine.

How to resolve this OR what's the best way to ping an IP address from a Vue app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping is a node.js module not supported in the browser. This module would need to run server-side.

This could be accomplished us axios where you issue a GET call to the url and if you get a 200 back that indicates a successful call. This could also be accomplished using $ajax.

axios example

```
const response = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox');

if (response.status === 200) {
  console.log('success'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even though it works I still get CORS error, and it effects the response time. do you know how to get around that?

Comment: CORS as you know if a result of one origin calling another. CORS needs to be resolved server side to grant the requesting party access to the api/domain. There is no browser bypass for this as it is built in security. If you are testing locally localhost:3000 that origin would need to be added to the servers Access-Control-Allow-Cross-Origin:localhost:3000 another option depending on how you are hosting is to build your own proxy to account for these requests. If you are getting CORS errors when calling random sites no work around for that unless you use some trust (OAuth) provider